# Change Magento 2 customer session timeout URL

Tags: session, magento2

I am working with Magento version 2.3.2 I want to change the customer session timeout URL. Currently when login customer is inactive for a while then page get session timeout and customer will redirect to the `customer/account/login/` I want to change this URL and redirect customer to other page.

For that in which file I need to change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your URL to

> Magento\Customer\Model\Session::authenticate()

```
// ...
$this->response->setRedirect(
    $this->_createUrl()->getUrl('your/custom/url', $arguments) // changed
);
// ...
```